# Can I pass file content to Krajee's JQuery bootstrap-file-input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've looked through the documentation [events](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#events) and [methods](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#methods) and I can't seem to find any way to pass data (FileContentResult) from my model to the bootstrap-file-input plugin in javascript. It doesn't look like there are any methods or events that will take or accept FileContentResult data from my model so that I can load up a picture that I'm sending from the server to my view.

ALl I can do right now is create a img tag and try to pas the data into it but it doesn't seem to be formatting correctly on the screen.

```
<input type="image" src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.StudentImageResult.FileContents)))" alt="" />
```

I want to pass to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StudentImageResult, new { @type = "file", @id = "input-20" })
```

So that when my page loads and fetches the image from my db it looks like this.
[image]

**UPDATE**
I do see a section [sending data to user from server](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#ajax-sync) here but there areno examples and I'm a newbie to Javascript. Can anyone help!

Comment: Hi, I have the same requirement, did you find a way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [initialPreview](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#option-initialpreview) setting to show image data for preview from your server on page load. You need to provide the image URL location on your server. You can check [some examples in the advanced usage section](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#advanced-usage) on the demo site.